# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::header()

Tags: php, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, I am trying to set the specific header to my route.

I have

```
Route::filter('api', function($response){
    $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    if (Input::get('key') != 'bheng')
    {
        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
    }
});
```

I kept getting

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::header()

I'm trying to set it, so I don't get the CORS error any more.

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors + http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/

Comment: Mine is Laravel 4.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Router::filter`, not `Route::filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)

> After filters receive a $response as the third argument passed to the filter

```
  Route::filter('log', function($route, $request, $response)

   {
        //
   })
```